# File.AppendAllText() vs File.OpenWrite() and minimizing disk time

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, io

I have a service that is responsible for frequently (5 second intervals) appending text to a file.

Currently it is simply calling the following line of code

```
File.AppendAllText(PATH_TO_File, item + Environment.NewLine);
```

This is currently causing a higher than normal 'blip' on the **% Disk Time** performance monitor, and we have only been testing it with a small amount of data. We are expecting to have 10x as much  data appended to these files.

I am curious if going a route with File.OpenWrite(...) would be better for performance. Is this reasonable? If so, is it a good idea to keep the FileStream open until I am ready to move to another file?

Comment: This should be super easy to test...

Comment: Sure, its fairly easy to test, however I wondering if this is a reasonable solution if it turned out to work, or if there is any hidden risk that I am missing.

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum Is it important for the appended text to be visible in the file between writes?  If you keep a single stream open and don't flush the buffer that wouldn't happen.  Also, if the program crashes without you flushing the buffer the information will be lost, unlike now.  If you do flush the buffer you'll likely lose most of the potential performance gains.

Comment: How big is tyour 'Blip' exactly? Is it a problem?  Keeping a Stream open saves on Open/Close at the cost of much more complicated resource management.  I would expect this to be relevant for 5ms writes, not for 5s.

Comment: `File.AppendAllText` internally create a stream and call `streamWriter.Write(contents);`.

Comment: It just happens to be the worst kind of file writes you could pick.  File.AppendAllText() completes very quickly, it copies the bytes to the file system cache.  From which it is lazily written to the drive.  You keep the drive constantly busy with high odds that you'll cause head seeks, the slowest operation.  Disk drives like large amounts of sequential data written infrequently.  So no, 10x as much data isn't going to make any difference.  Nor does File.OpenWrite().  Buffering the data will reduce the number.

Comment: What's the actual problem to solve? Usually, this is about being able to read the file while appending is occurring, in which case setting the appropriate sharing options whilst opening the file for writing are far more important - you can keep the file open for a long time but still allow readers to access it.